# Jira Structure quick transformation: How to show only groups which names are equal to currentUser()?

Tags: structure, jira

I'm trying to write quick transformation for Jira structure, which show me only groups (with children) with name equal to current user login. Somthing like this (in S-JQL)

```
child of [currentUser()]
```

But this didn't works.
Is there some way to solve my task?